# Email address not accepted

Tags: ubuntu-one, email

I am trying to set up a Ubuntu One account on my wife's laptop.  When we put her email address in, it will not accept it.

I already have an account on my laptop and I can't remember having this problem when I set it up.

Comment: You mean like it won't accept the format? Or that the correctly typed email is somehow banned or blocked? Try logging in to Ubuntu One in the browser and check that the email address is the same as you are typing it in the U1 application. If you get any specific errors post a screenshot or type the exact error, it will help us diagnose the problem faster.

Comment: @TomBrossman - Can you please put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Done, but this question should really be flagged as Too localized + Abandoned.

Comment: @TomBrossman - Yes I already flagged it as such. The problem is very localized although your comment might help the user if he comes back.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging in to Ubuntu One in your browser and check that the email address is the same as you are typing it in the Ubuntu One desktop application.

If you get any more errors post a screenshot or type the exact error, it will help us diagnose the problem faster.